# Are all $L^2 = cI$ live in the same conjugacy classes in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $L \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $L^2 = cI$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Are all the linear transformations in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ similar to this one? Or are all the linear transformations with $L^2 = cI$ live in the same conjugacy classes? From $(gLg^{-1})^2 = gL^2g^{-1} = gcIg^{-1} = cI$ we could get all the conjugation of $L$ have such property. But is the converse true? I tried to use the intersection of two conjugacy classes to prove this but that leads nothing.

Comment: It is bad style to change the question after it has been answered. Just ask a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Take $c=1$ and $L=I$, we have that for any $g$, $gIg^{-1} = I$, so the conjugacy class is ${I}$. However, $(-I)^2 = I$, thus $-I$ respects the property.